# get_the_post_thumbnail_url with an unregistered size

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, thumbnails, cropping

The [official code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/) for `get_the_post_thumbnail_url` states:

> $size (string|array) (Optional) Registered image size to retrieve the source for **or a flat array of height and width dimensions**.

(emphasis mine).

I'm using the following parameters:

```
$img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(), array('300' , '170'));
```

But it doesn't return the size I want.

The registered image sizes are 150 x 150, 300 x 300 and 1024 x 1024.

Answer (score 3):

WordPress does not create any thumbnail on the fly. If you try to fetch a size that doesn't exist, either the closest size or the full size image will be retrieved.

The closest solution you can try is to fetch a size larger than what you want, and then size it down via CSS and crop it.

Let's say the registered sizes are `50 x 150`, `300 x 300` and `1024 x 1024`, but you need a `300x177` image. Fetch the `300x300` one, and then [clip](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp) it using CSS:

```
#my-div img {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect( 0px, 300px, 177px, 0px );
}
```